# How to rate someone who answered my query?

Tags: support

How to give badges to other . actually I asked a question at you site and I got my answer, now I want to thank him by giving him some rating or badge like that

Comment: I noticed the answer to your question didn't have any up votes yet. You could vote on the answer next to accepting it

Answer (score 13):

Your options as the asker of the question are laid out in this Help Center article:

- [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

> Decide if the answer is helpful, and then...
>
> - Vote on it (if you have earned the appropriate voting privilege). [Vote up](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) answers that are helpful and well-researched, and [vote down](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down) answers that are not. Other users will also vote on answers to your question.
> - Accept it. As the asker, you have a special privilege: you may [accept the answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) that you believe is the best solution to your problem.

If the answer is exceptionally good, and you have earned the [set bounties](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) privilege (75 rep required), you may also [set a bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067).

As for [badges](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/badges), they are awarded by the system, not by users or moderators.

Feel free to visit the [Help Center](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about how this site works.

For a quick introduction, you can also take the [Tour](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/tour).